# JavaScript works in Firefox, not in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

This code works when loaded in Firefox, but does not work in IE8. In IE8, clicking the link has no effect.

I would appreciate any pointers on how to make it work in IE.

```
     <html>
       <head>
        <title>RG</title>
      </head> 
   <script type="text/javascript">

      var rightTarget;
      var leftTarget;
      var index = 516;
      var img;
      function rightLinkClicked(e) {
        rightTarget = e.target;
            rightTarget.style.color = "green";
        if (index < 547) {
       index = index +1;
               img=document.getElementById("img");
               img.src="pics/IMG_0" + index + ".JPG";
           } else {
      alert ("This is the last painting");
        }
      }

      function leftLinkClicked(e) {
        leftTarget = e.target;
            leftTarget.style.color = "red";
            rightTarget.style.color = "black";
        if (index >516) {
            index = index -1;
                    img=document.getElementById('img');
                    img.src="pics/IMG_0" + index + ".JPG";
        } else {
       alert ("This is the first painting");
            }   
            }

       function addListeners() {
        var rightLink = document.getElementById("rightlinkid");
            rightLink.addEventListener('click', rightLinkClicked, false);
            var leftLink = document.getElementById("leftlinkid");

            leftLink.addEventListener('click', leftLinkClicked, false);
           }
           window.addEventListener('load', addListeners, false);

      </script>   
      </head>   
      <body>
         <h2>RG</h2>
         <div>
         <a id="leftlinkid">Previous
     <img src="icons/left.gif" ;="" alt="left arrow" title="">
         </a>
        </div>
    <div id="myimg">        
          <img id="img" src="pics/IMG_0516.JPG" ;="" alt="start arrow"           title=""width="640"height="480">
</div>
<div>
<a id="rightlinkid">Next
<img src="icons/right.gif" ;="" alt="right arrow" title="">
</a>
</div>        
<p>© 2011 RG</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE uses [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `addEventListener`.

You may want to use a cross-browser Javascript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery) to handle these issues (and many more) for you.

Comment: Thanks, any quick pointers on how to modify the code to use jQuery?